# WEBM background and Bootstrap nav bar lagging at Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, background, webm

I've got one-page site at http://vanillaproject.ru/your-rp/ (my development domain, no ads there and here)

And my question is: why the nav bar and first row background lag when I have WEBM-backgrounded div at bottom? Chrome is the one who lags, Opera and FF seems to be ok about this. When I remove the video from background everything goes OK, but i really need it.

I'm using VIDE jQuery plugin to make webm background. I can provide any source code you need, but this page has no PHP back-end, so all codes are available from dev console.

Thanks!

Comment: Not a final solution, but if you take out "fixed" from the background rule on the css on your first div element the navbar behaves normally (and you still have the video running). Not sure if this is a bug with chrome or there is something really wrong with your background image (in fact, it renders in a really strange way for me).

Comment: @MaCK Renders bad for me aswell. Will try out your hack and report how it did.